# Make change index option in jComboBox from another jComboBox

Tags: java, jcombobox

Hy guys. I want to ask about my problem with jComboBox. 
My problem is when I'm select index in comBox1, I want in comBox2's index is changed too. Here my source:

```
private void comBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
if(comBox1.getSelectedIndex()==0){
comBox2.setSelectedIndex(0);
}
}
```

When I'm run it, there is error message like this:
    Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.IlegalArgumentException: setSelectedIndex: 0 out of bounds

Please, how to solve this?

Comment: your comBox2 seems to be empty.

Comment: In initComponents i have set item with comBox1.addItem("my items"); and comBox2.addItem("other items");

Comment: Before it, I was set my items in initComponents